# iOS, is there a way to programmatically turn off three fingered zoom

Tags: ios, accessibility

I have an iPad app that is being used as part of a museum exhibit, it runs in guided access mode. I have enabled three fingered zoom on the iPad for accessibility. Users are finding it confusing if the previous user has entered the zoom mode and left it zoomed in.

The app times out and enters an attract mode after it is inactive for a period of time. When it enters the attract loop I would like to leave the zoomed mode, is it possible to do this programmatically or does it have to be done manually?

Comment: You mean pinch? Yes. But you have to show your codes first (to show how you zoom your contents)

Comment: Nope not pinch to zoom, three fingered tap to zoom, it is enable by Settings > General > Accessibility > Zoom. It is an Accessibility option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to be done manually. Your app can't communicate with the accessibility features. It's true that three-fingered zoom on the iPad can be confusing; I've triggered it accidentally and confused myself! But for that very reason I suggest that you do *not* turn on this feature in your kiosk iPad. A better option would be to enable some form of zoom *within the app itself*. That would be something that you *can* turn off programmatically.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of, just needed to confirm before I went and reinvented the wheel. Thank you.

Comment: Well it's not a very difficult wheel to reinvent, so take heart.

Comment: I've implemented pinch to zoom for the images used in the app with a UIScrollView but I'm not sure where to start with more complex elements, for example I have a paging UIScrollView which takes up 1/4 of the screen with static language select buttons layered over top which is all layered over a full screen image. I don't see a way of mimicking the full app zoom of the three finger tap, short of overlaying the entire app with a ScrollView and then passing touch events through to the elements below. Either I am missing something or our versions of not very difficult vary greatly.

Comment: Well, a gesture recognizer will track what the user is doing (a pinch, let's say). Or you could just add a zoom button or slider. I don't know your app or its interface. As for the actual zooming, you might just apply a scale transform (that's what UIScrollView does, after all). Or yes, why not, just wrap your whole interface in a scroll view and let it do the work.