# Check programmatically if the zoom function is activated on the Apple device

Tags: ios, objective-c, zooming

I need to know if the zoom function is activated on the Apple devices. This because in my App "AAccompanist" you can press up to 10 buttons simultaneously (e.g. to play chords). I am also interested, if the zoom function can be deactivated in the App programmatically.
Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Partial duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26007723/3151675

Comment: Why do you need to know if the device is setup for "zoom"? Your app should work no matter what the screen size is.

Comment: Try using my App, when multi finger touching is used for special functions. You can't play chords etc. By the way, zooming a piano keyboard or accordion keyboard makes really no sense.

Comment: All multifinger gestures must be disabled for playing with the "AAccompanist" (Accordion and Piano with accompaniment).

Answer (score 1):

Apple technical support wrote me, that this is not possible and so I wrote a Bug Report. Now I hope of a feedback from Apple.
If I put this line im my code, the user will be advertised about a possible conflict between the App and the multi finger gestures enabled:

```
UIAccessibilityRegisterGestureConflictWithZoom();
```

But the question pop up window is only shown once. When the user switches on again later the multi finger features, then no more warning will be displayed.